# higher Casimirs for $\mathfrak{sl}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-algebras, invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

The Wikipedia  [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra#Rank) suggest a way to obtain higher Casimir operators (e.g. generators of the center of $\mathfrak{U(g)}$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ semisimple) by evaluating certain determinant:

$$
\det\, (t\mathrm{I} - \mathrm{ad}_X) = \sum_{i=0}^{\dim \mathfrak{g}} p_i(X) t^i
$$

However if one does that for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ then the resulting polynomial has only degrees (in $t$) 0,1,2,4,6,8 and it's coefficients seem to be just powers of the quadratic Casimir operator. If one tries to do the same for the defining representation $\mathbb{C}^3$ (replacing $\mathrm{ad}_X$ by $\rho(X)$ in the above formula) then one obtains quadratic as well as cubic invariant polynomials.

In the proof of Harish-Chandra isomorphism as presented e.g. in (1) there is construction of elements of $Z(\mathfrak{U(g)}$ using traces of matrices from representations of $\mathfrak{g}$. Something like
$$
\sum\mathrm{tr}(\rho(X_{i_1})\rho(X_{i_2})\ldots \rho(X_{i_n}))X_{i_1}^*X_{i_2}^*\ldots X_{i_n}^*
$$
where $X_i$ form basis for $\mathfrak{g}$ and $X_i^*$ form dual basis with respect to Killing form.

> Q1: What is going on here?
>
> Q2: Is it true that for a semi-simple complex Lie algebra and it's
>   smallest nontrivial representation one obtains in this way all
>   generators of the $Z(\mathfrak{U(g)}$?
>
> Q3:  Does the approach through determinant give the same operators that appear in the proof of the H-Ch isomorphism?

(1) *Cohomological Induction and Unitary Representations* by Knapp, Vogan

Comment: Related questions: 1. cubic Casimir for sl3 - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188266/what-is-the-cubic-casimir-element-of-sl-3

Comment: Related questions 2. calculating central elements - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417897/calculating-central-elements-of-universal-enveloping-algebras

Comment: None of the above have a full answer for calculating all central elements for all semisimple Lie algebra yet.

Answer (score 3):

For $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ the coefficients are not powers of the Casimir, though the polynomial is one in the square of $t$.

Comment: To be completely honest we haven't tried all coefficients but we checked that the highest degree $p_i$ is indeed a power of Casimir. I've checked again and I discovered I've missed linear term that is there. But all the other odd degrees of $t$ are missing.

Comment: Does "the polynomial is one in the square of $t$" mean "the polynomial has non-$0$ terms only in even degrees"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for the editing. The typos were too many!

Comment: The coefficients are naturally elements of $\mathcal S(\mathfrak g^*)$ (and not $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g^*)$). If you symmetrize the coefficient of $t^6$ and evaluate it at the dual basis, you obtain the quadratic Casimir. However, the cubic one is missing, since the coefficient of $t^5$ is $0$. There is a non-zero coefficient next to $t$ (which is of degree $7$), so cubic Casimir might be hidden there?